# Create a notation summary in latex?

Tags: tables, math-mode, amsmath

Hi guys I'm writing a report with a lot of math symbols that I would like to collect in a single table at the beginning of the document, like some math books do. Is there a simple way to do that?

Morevoer, since there are some important equations, I would like to summarize them too.

So I was thinking a of creating the following:

1. Notation summary.
2. Equation summary.

For the point 2 I have been thinking something like the table of Fourier/inverse Fourier transform pair, but where one column has a very short description and the other has the equation.

How to do this as well?

(The picture below shows what kind of result i want to achieve)

[image]

Comment: You can do that with `nomencl`, `glosstex` or `glossaries`.

Comment: What's the difference among them?

Comment: As far as I know (never used any of them), nomencl is specialised  in lists of symbols, glossaries is powerful general system that can use xindy. You might want to take a look at their documentations, e. g. via the [TeX catalogue on line](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/alpha.html)

Comment: Devil's advocate here. I have made a manual table for notations on my thesis without relying on packages, even though I used `glossaries` for acronyms. This is because I found it just as easy if not easier to make a manual table for notation and symbols. Using say `glossaries` would require putting commands on first mention of every symbol I want, and which means it's all over the place. I will put an example answer later.

Comment: @MobiusPizza: Using `\glsaddall` will provide all defined symbols, regardless whether they are used or not

Comment: I think an example with each of these would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example for the symbol notation table with `glossaries`, removing the page numbers by applying a user-defined glossary-style.

Say `\glsaddall` to provide all symbols at once!

```
\documentclass{book}                              
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR SYMBOLS LIST =========================================
    \newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
        description={Geometrical value},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
        description={Height of tower},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{energyconsump}{name=\ensuremath{P},
        description={Energy consumption},
        type=symbolslist}





\newglossarystyle{notationlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%

\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description \\
 \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
  & \glossentrydesc{##1}
  \tabularnewline
}

}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=notationlong]   % list of symbols


\blindtext


\glsaddall


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity does it work even for paper the glossaries? or should it be a book?

Comment: @Lukkio: It works of course for `article`, `report` etc. too

Comment: Why when i try to compile it says "Option clash for package glossaries"?

Comment: @Lukkio: Well, not for me -- do you have an old TeX distribution?

Comment: Ho do i check it? I use texworks as editor and miktex is 2.9, is that old?

Comment: Texworks is an irrelevant information. MikTeX 2.9 seems new.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again... is there a way to have a section with the notation? (like the one in the picture i posted) you have both notation and text in the same page, instead i would like to have a section with simbols.

Comment: @Lukkio: I don't understand. `Symbolslist` is a section. Remove the `\blindtext` which was only used as a filler