# Glossary Longtable Layout Swap and width adjustment

Tags: tables, glossaries

I found this nice code from Christian Hupfer for a glossary setup. I would like to change the order of Description and Unit (Symbol,Unit,Description) but I can't find a way how to adjust the width for the columns when swapped. What do I have to do to get the description width longer than symbol & unit width?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}                           % documentclass: scrbook
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR SYMBOLS LIST =========================================
    \newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
        description={Geometrical value},
        unit={},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
        description={Height of tower},
        unit={\si{m}},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{energyconsump}{name=\ensuremath{P},
        description={Energy consumption},
        unit={\si{kW}},
        type=symbolslist}




% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR ACRONYMS LIST ========================================
    \newacronym{VRBD}{VRBD}{Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR MAIN GLOSSARY ========================================
    \newglossaryentry{Biofouling}{name=Biofouling,description={Some description}}


\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}


\begin{document}

    \glsaddall

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]  % list of acronyms
    \printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % list of symbols
    \printglossary[type=main]                     % main glossary

\end{document}
```

I used the following style instead and I get close to what I need.

```
\newglossarystyle{3colger}{%
    \setglossarystyle{longragged3col}% base this style on the list style
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
        \begin{longtable}{l l p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    %
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
        \bfseries Zeichen & \bfseries Einheit & \bfseries Beschreibung \\
%       \hline
        \vspace{0.05cm}
        \endhead}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
        & \glsunit{##1} 
        &  \glossentrydesc{##1}  \tabularnewline
    }
}
```

The problem which remains is, that if the 3rd column's entry gets to long, it will not break. Is there a way to get a clean break?

Comment: Well, it would be nice to link to the code  of this ominous bloke named Christian Hupfer ;-) You meant this question and the relevant answer:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274202/create-a-notation-summary-in-latex

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your answer! Problem is that this one only has 2 columns. How can I add the third one, i don't quite get the concept of {longtable}.